# Opencv cvThreshold bug

Tags: c++, opencv

Hello I don t know if I am doing something wrong or not but when I do the following:

```
IplImage *testimage;
testimage = cvCreateImage(cvSize(10,10),IPL_DEPTH_8U,1);
cvThreshold(testimage,testimage,127,127,CV_THRESH_TRUNC);
```

everything works fine then when I try to use unsigned short values:

```
IplImage *testimage;
testimage = cvCreateImage(cvSize(10,10),IPL_DEPTH_16U,1);
cvThreshold(testimage,testimage,127,127,CV_THRESH_TRUNC);
```

my program crashes... I use opencv 2.4.2 I think this could maybe be a bug in opencv.
Somehow if I try the following:

```
IplImage *testimage;
testimage = cvCreateImage(cvSize(10,10),IPL_DEPTH_16S,1);
cvThreshold(testimage,testimage,127,127,CV_THRESH_TRUNC);
```

it doesn t crash anymore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not crashing. It is throwing an exception and since you are not catching it, your program is aborting.
OpenCV Thresholding does not support 16U.

```
The supported ones are: 8U, 16S and 32F
```

Answer (score 1):

See the OpenCV documentation for function [threshold](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=cvthreshold#double%20cvThreshold%28const%20CvArr%2a%20src,%20CvArr%2a%20dst,%20double%20threshold,%20double%20max_value,%20int%20threshold_type%29). The first parameter is 8 or 32 bit image
P.S. In crash message you should see the reason for crashing